# How to stop Web API execution in mid by Volley

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, android-volley

I have requirement to call 12 web APIs in starting when my application launch          first time to get all data from database in local mobile DB, I am using volley.
My requirement is if among 12 web APIs any one gets fail due to network error or time out or any other then volley execution must stop at the same instant.
Any one please let me know How to do it.

I have tried by clearing cache as well as cancel in on error method of volley, but still I am egtting response of further web APIs.

**Calling Web APis**

```
 for (String data : mWebApiList) {
        switch (data) {
            //Dashboard
            case data1:
                webAPICalling.callDashBoardApi(mContext, this);
                break;
            //Loan Type
            case data2:
                webAPICalling.callLoanTypeWebApi(mContext, this);
                break;
            //Help FAQs
            case data3::
                webAPICalling.callHelpFaqsWebAPI(mContext, this,false);
                break;
               :
               :
              break;


        }
    }
```

In error I am cancelling all request, but let suppose 3 and 7 web api become fail,still on success is calling for all 4 5 6 8 9 and on error for 7 as well. I want that after 3 no other web api can exevute.

```
    public void onError(String status) {

    SFApplication. getInstance().getRequestQueue().clearAll(TAG);
    SFApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to call `cancel()` on each request in turn, although that's what `cancelAll(TAG)` does as well.

There's more info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#cancel) as well about how to cancel a request.

The thing is, it only guarantees not to call your request handlers, but it might not stop the request from being completed. That is, a full HTTP request-response dance might happen, just that the library checks that a request hasn't been cancelled before invoking response handlers. Looking at [NetworkDispatcher.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/com/android/volley/NetworkDispatcher.java), [ExecutorDelivery.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/com/android/volley/ExecutorDelivery.java) and [Request.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/com/android/volley/Request.java) seems to corroborate this as well (search for cancel).

You could try specifying a single executor thread, so requests are sent serially, but then you'll have worse performance in the normal case of all 12 requests working.

Comment: Thanks Horia, I am trying the same to cancel all request, in place of stop I am doing that in onError method, but still all request execution takes place completely. I have updated my code as well in detail.

Comment: It isn't clear from the details what your app's architecture is, but it seems like you're adding the requests fairly quickly at the start of your app. Volley will try to do all 12 requests in parallel (up to some configuration you specify). It's gonna take some time for the one request to fail, so by that time, others will be in flight, and, as the answer tells you, there's no TCP/IP or HTTP level cancelling of requests which are in flight. You just don't get notified about them.

Comment: Hello Horia,"You just don't get notified about them," you are saying that I will not get notified about them, but i am getting callback in on response if getting success else in on error(). Is there any way to stop notification about them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like @Horia said, the volley requests would be called in parallel. For the requirement you are trying can be achieved by nesting web api calls, like execute the next web api after success of the 1st api and so on. I hope this will help.